# Lambda Calculus Syntax

Tags: lambda-calculus

I've got my exams in a couple of weeks time and as part of my studying I consistently come across the question:

Give the syntax for the simply typed lambda calculus i.e. terms, types and the rules for well-formedness.

I've been reading through some material here and there and from what I can make out the terms are:

> M ::= c | x | λx:T.M' | M<sub>1</sub>M<sub>2</sub>

and types are:

> T ::= T<sub>1</sub>->T<sub>2</sub> | Bool | Int

But I'm struggling with the rules. Could anyone help with the rules, and also confirm that my types and terms are correct?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: SOLVED

Terms:

> t ::= x | λx.t | t<sub>1</sub>t<sub>2</sub>

and types are:

> T ::= B | T<sub>1</sub>->T<sub>2</sub>

Rules:

> x:T<sub>1</sub> t=T<sub>2</sub>
>   
> --------------
>   
> λx.t = T<sub>1</sub>->T<sub>2</sub>
>   
>   
> and
>   
>   
>   t<sub>1</sub>=T<sub>1</sub>->T<sub>2</sub> t<sub>2</sub>=T<sub>1</sub>
>   
> --------------------
>   
> t<sub>1</sub>t<sub>2</sub>:T<sub>2</sub>

Comment: I don't see a question there but this looks like a BNF - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form where M is an expression that can be either `c` or `x` or lambda function with argument `x` here I'm not sure what `T.M'` is but I guess it's another expression named `M'` of type `T` or two expressions `M1` and `M2`, here I'm not sure again but I guess that `M1` takes `M2` as an argument. Then `T` would be a type that can be either `Int` or `Bool` or function taking type `T1` as argument and returning type `T2`.

Comment: Oh well, you can just find the terms at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus

Comment: So the expression looks correct but I'm not sure about the types. Maybe. Anyway, I guess it's kind of meaningless without further explanation what the expressions mean like on wiki above

Comment: Thanks for the replies for i've found them now =]

Comment: If you've found your answers make sure to write an answer here to your own question. That way people looking this question up in the future can find your information. It's completely okay to answer your own questions on SO.